# Derivative of a constant

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

Why is the derivative of $1^{\sin x}$ is equal to $0$ ? Why can't I apply the constant with power of function to this. So it would be $1^{\sin x}(\ln 1)(\cos x) $

Comment: $ln 1 = 0$ itself Hence zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the rule: $\frac{d}{dx} 1^{\sin(x)}=1^{\sin(x)}\ln(1)\cos(x)$. But $\ln(1)=0,$ so $\frac{d}{dx} 1^{\sin(x)}=1^{\sin(x)}(0)\cos(x)=0$. So both conclusions are correct.